# DNS not working after suspend (19.04)

Tags: wireless, suspend, dns, broadcom, 19.04

After closing and reopening laptop lid my system wakes up from suspend and after connecting to wifi I can ping to 8.8.8.8 but can't ping to google.com and it shows error **Temporary failure in name resolution**.

To fix this I need to restart my system, but when I attempt to restart or even power off, my system to goes to a black screen with blinking cursor.

To find out why my system is not restarting I removed **quiet splash** from grub config and saw the errors on restart like **failed to unmount All Filesystems** as shown in the image 
[screen snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B147Z.jpg)

Output of **sudo lshw -class network** is

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: ec:8e:b5:a2:8d:39
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:32 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1004000-f1004fff memory:f1000000-f1003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 01
       serial: 44:1c:a8:a9:86:43
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.201 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:36 memory:f0300000-f0307fff
```

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal  `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`. Change the ip adress after `nameserver` as `8.8.8.8` or another dns server adress. 
If you want to change dns in one command try this

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8">>resolv.conf

echo "sudo cp resolv.conf /etc/">>dns.sh.
```

You have created dns.sh. You can run the `dns.sh` with `./dns.sh` to change dns easly.

Comment: adding 8.8.8.8 in /etc/resolv.conf does works . But it changes back to what it was before after waking up from suspend or during boot and during restart it shows "**A stop job is running for network name resolution**" which runs for a minute or so and after that same errors occurs that I have shown in image attached to the original post. And then I have to force shutdown.

Comment: @Saurabh try to run     sudo service network-manager restart    . After that run dns.sh